# Como substituir um elemento float por string numa matriz zerada?

Tags: python, matriz

Gerei uma matriz zerada através do código:

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.zeros([4,4])
```

Depois, tentei substituir um elemento da matriz por uma string qualquer (por exemplo "a"). Porém deu erro.

```
lista[0][0]="a"
```

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Não faz sentido você ter uma matriz heterogênea. Por que precisa ter zeros e *strings* na mesma matriz?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que definir o tipo da array que você está criando para que ela possa aceitar uma string, ou um caractere:
Ao definir o tipo da array como S1, ela salvará somente o primeiro caractere da string:

```
import numpy as np 

lista = np.zeros([4,4], dtype='|S1')
lista[0][0] = 'Aaaaa'
```

O resultado do código acima será:

```
[['A' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']]
```

Já se você quer salvar uma String inteira, deve atribuir como "dtype" o valor '|S5':

```
import numpy as np 

lista = np.zeros([4,4], dtype='|S5')
lista[0][0] = 'Aaaaaa'
```

E o resultado será:

```
[['Aaaaa' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '']]
```

[Aqui está a documentação referente a esses dtypes de uma matriz numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).